# Multiple and seperate SFMC orgs to 1 CRM org

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

Would it be possible to connect different SFMC Orgs (not BUs) to 1 single salesforce CRM?

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not possible. You cannot connect different SFMC orgs to the same Salesforce CRM Org. Check out the below documentation -

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_faqs_for_multi_org.htm&type=5

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_multi_org_scenario_examples.htm&type=5

In a Salesforce CRM org, you can provide credentials of only one SFMC org.

Answer (score -3):

Yes, It is possible.
It is as same as connecting multiple BU to a Salesforce Org.